# i'm having this error with the flutter version for web each time i try to test it. But it works fine on mobile

Tags: flutter

Everything works fine and App is already in the play store but when i try to test for a web version it produces below error just for this particular App.

I want to know what is exactly wrong

> lib/main.dart:15:8: Error: Error when reading
> 'lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart': The system cannot find the
> file specified.
>
> import 'package:[NameOfApp goes
> here]/generated_plugin_registrant.dart';
>
> ^ lib/main.dart:16:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart': The system cannot find the
> file specified.

> org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart:11:3: Error: Method not found: 'registerPlugins'.
> registerPlugins(webPluginRegistry);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

> Failed to compile application.

Comment: How do you "try to test for a web version"?

Comment: i toggled the chrome(web) option and it gave me this error.  I even switched to edge(web) and Web Server(web) still yet i get same error.The  API level of the App on the Play store is now 30. When i created the web version of the App at first it worked properly, but was then API level 28. I then noticed this error when i tried again to run the web version after the API upgrade. I'm not sure if any of this is connected but this is how and when i began to get the error . And if i create another starter App the web version works fine but for this App it gives errors as described above.

Comment: @Catenin95 Did you solve it?

Comment: I was able to solve it using the Flutter SDk Command Line.

I solved it by using the cd  command to navigate to where all my Flutter projects where  eg.

C:/Users/cd applications/ cd flutter projects/ cd ... Until I got to the exact flutter application folder that was giving me this issue.

Then using the command  "flutter create ."

It regenerated the folder for the web and all missing files that gave the errors were fixed.